# Strip variable number of commas from double-quoted csv field

Tags: mysql, regex, csv, sed

How can I write a sed script (or awk, just not familiar with it) to stip commas from the innards of a double-quoted csv field? I can remove a single comma using the following sed one-liner:

```
sed 's/"\([^"]*\),\([^"]*\)"/\1\2/g' file > file2
```

But if I have two commas in the field only has one comma stripped:

> "ALOHA, INC., A CONDOMINIUM ASSOCIATION"

becomes

> "ALOHA, INC. A CONDOMINIUM ASSOCIATION"

Alternatively, if someone can explain to me why I can't seem to get the 'OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ' " ' option to work when loading csv's into mysql, that would make life a hell of a lot easier (I've been trying to use sed to strip the commas because commas destroy my columnar data even when I use the optionally enclosed option and my fields are double quoted. Excel exports with quotes only around fields with commas. If everything is double-quoted, I don't have a problem, but with selectively-quoted, I start banging my shoe on the desk.

**Update:** The file includes multiple fields.

> "ALOHA, INC., A CONDOMINIUM ASSOCIATION", 900, VENICE, FL, 34293-5112,,VENICE,FL,34285,ALOHA

I'm even concerned there might be rows that have multiple quoted fields, which seems like it could be a serious problem. As far as I can tell it's not that common, though.

One thing I was just thinking is I could eliminate all instances of ', INC' but that wouldn't eliminate other examples, like ', LLC', etc.

I want to remove all commas from within a field.

I'm worried about cases such as:

> "ALOHA, INC., A CONDOMINIUM ASSOCIATION", 900, VENICE, FL, 34293-5112,,VENICE,FL,34285,"ALOHA, Inc., A CONDOMINIUM ASSOCIATION"

Wouldn't the commas between the first instance of Aloha and the last instance be eliminated with

```
sed 's/"\([^"]*\),\([^"]*\)"/\1\2/g' file > file2
```

Comment: Try `sed '/"[^"]*"/s/,//g' file > file2`

Comment: @malan, does your line has only one field or multiple fields? giving a sample that reflects your real use case is important.. or you might gets answers assuming only one double quoted field in a line..

Comment: also, could you clarify what should be done to double quoted fields with 1 comma, 3 commas, 4 commas, etc... your given sample is for a field with 2 comma out of which you want to remove the second comma..

Comment: Sundeep: if a row has 2 double quoted fields in a line will it eliminate a field separating comma? I'm thinking based on sed and regex it would.

Comment: Do you want to keep the double-quotes or eliminate them?

Comment: ...and if you know, which version of sed are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNU awk for this case

```
$ gawk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/,/, "", $i)} 1' ip.txt
"ALOHA INC. A CONDOMINIUM ASSOCIATION", 900, VENICE, FL, 34293-5112,,VENICE,FL,34285,"ALOHA Inc. A CONDOMINIUM ASSOCIATION"
```

- `-v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*'` define input field as double quoted fields, or those separated by comma

  - See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html for details
- `-v OFS=,` comma as output field separator
- `for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)` loop over all input fields

  - `gsub(/,/, "", $i)` delete all commas
- `1` print contents of `$0`

If `gawk` is not available, you can use

```
perl -pe 's/"[^"]+"/$&=~tr|,||dr/ge' ip.txt
```

Note: This won't work if a field contains double quote, newline, etc. Use `csv` parsers available in `perl`, `python`, etc

Comment: Thank you sundeep. This is a pretty strong reminder than I need to learn awk.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all occurrences of commas between `"` to `"` then following may help you.

```
sed '/".*"/s/,//g'   Input_file
```

Use `sed -i` option in case you want to save output into Input_file itself.

Comment: OP mentions removing one comma from a field with two commas.. not very clear though..

Comment: @Sundeep What part if 'I want to remove all commas from within a field' didn't you understand?

Comment: @EJP didn't understand OP's wording and got confused with sample (thought expected output was given).. `remove all commas` was added in the edit